# How to implement Gmail IMAP with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, omniauth

I've read through several desperate sources of information on connecting to Google's Gmail through XOAUTH:
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#imap

And I'm trying the use the 'gmail' gem which implements IMAP:
https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

Finally, ominauth for handling the authentication:
https://github.com/Yesware/omniauth-google

**How do I actually tie these codes together to make something usable?**
Please let me know of any real world implementations, here's some examples of connecting to Gmail: 
http://otherinbox.com 
http://goslice.com

Comment: I am having the same problem , i have been struggling to make this work but i could not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had trouble, like you, using existing gems since Google's XOAUTH is now deprecated. You should use their new XOAUTH2.

Here is a working example of fetching email from Google using their XOAUTH2 protocol. This example uses the [`mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail), [`gmail_xoauth`](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth), [`omniauth`](http://www.omniauth.org/), and [`omniauth-google-oauth2`](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) gems.

You will also need to register your app in [Google's API console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) in order to get your API tokens.

```
# in an initializer:
ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'] = 'yourkey'
ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'] = 'yoursecret'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'], {
    scope: 'https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
  }

end

# in your script
email = auth_hash[:info][:email]
access_token = auth_hash[:credentials][:token]

imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', email, access_token)
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(['ALL']).each do |message_id|

    msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
    mail = Mail.read_from_string msg

    puts mail.subject
    puts mail.text_part.body.to_s
    puts mail.html_part.body.to_s

end
```

Comment: This was really helpful thanks. I was using the "gmail" gem, and switching out to "gmail_xoauth" seemed to unstick the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this solution works anymore. I keep getting: 
Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Invalid credentials (Failure)